# save button showing on facebook share

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, facebook-share

We are using this example to share content on facebook.

http://flowplayer.blacktrash.org/fbshare.html

But when we are sharing as per example its showing a save button on share dialog. Please tell us how we can remove this.

```
<meta name="medium" content="video">
<meta name="title" content="Flowplayer Demo Video">
<meta name="description" content=
"This Flowplayer demo video is coming from a page providing only the most minimal content to share a video on Facebook with Flowplayer.">
<meta name="video_type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash">
<meta name="video_height" content="300">
<meta name="video_width" content="500">
<link rel="video_src" href=
"http://flowplayer.blacktrash.org/flowplayer-3.2.18.swf?config=%7B%27clip%27%3A%7B%27url%27%3A%27http%3A%2F%2Fstream.flowplayer.org%2Fflowplayer-700.flv%27%7D%7D">
<link rel="image_src" href="http://flowplayer.org/img/home/flow_eye.jpg">
<meta property="og:url" content="http://flowplayer.blacktrash.org/fbshare.html">
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Flowplayer Demos">
<meta property="og:type" content="movie">
<meta property="og:title" content="Flowplayer Demo Video">
<meta property="og:description" content=
"This Flowplayer demo video is coming from a page providing only the most minimal content to share a video on Facebook with Flowplayer.">
<meta property="og:video:height" content="300">
<meta property="og:video:width" content="500">
<meta property="og:image" content="http://flowplayer.org/img/home/flow_eye.jpg">
<meta property="og:image:secure_url" content=
"https://d12zt1n3pd4xhr.cloudfront.net/fp/img/flow_eye.jpg">
<meta property="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash">
<meta property="og:video" content=
"http://flowplayer.blacktrash.org/flowplayer-3.2.18.swf?config=%7B%27clip%27%3A%7B%27url%27%3A%27http%3A%2F%2Fstream.flowplayer.org%2Fflowplayer-700.flv%27%7D%7D">
<meta property="og:video:secure_url" content=
"https://d12zt1n3pd4xhr.cloudfront.net/fp/swf/flowplayer-3.2.18.swf?config=%7B%27clip%27%3A%7B%27url%27%3A%27https%3A%2F%2Fd12zt1n3pd4xhr.cloudfront.net%2Ffp%2Fflowplayer-700.flv%27%7D%7D">
```

Comment: Can you show a screenshot? This is probably just part of Facebook’s “save to read later” feature.

Comment: save button same as in given example link. May be you are right its a part of "save to read later", but client don't want it. So how can we remove this?

Comment: Tell client it doesn’t matter what they “want” – it is a feature that is useful to users, and therefor Facebook displays it when they feel it is appropriate.

Comment: we will tell but may be our client not agree on this. Is there is no way to remove this button?